# Is there a class of real functions strictly between $C^{\infty}$ (smooth) and $C^{\omega}$ (analytic)?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, analytic-functions

I'm relatively new to the concept of analytic functions, and began wondering: Is it possible to exist a class of functions strictly between $C^{\infty}$ (smooth functions) and $C^{\omega}$ (analytic functions)?

In other words, could there be a class $C^{\alpha}$ of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f \in C^{\omega} \Rightarrow f \in C^{\alpha} \Rightarrow f \in  C^{\infty}$, but $f \in C^{\infty} \nRightarrow f \in C^{\alpha}$ and $f \in C^{\alpha} \nRightarrow f \in C^{\omega}$? If so, what coud be this class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for example the [Gevrey class](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gevrey_class).

Comment: See also the Wikipedia article for [Quasi-analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function), which is written for a much less specialized audience.